# google maps Distance

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hey guys :) i got a question, i got some experience with java and xml (if that cares) and try to programm a google maps app. I already made a Location Marker for my Location and for a Location near a park . The Park Marker got a circle too ... My next step is, that when the Circles of my location and the park location meets, it creates an easy window. I can create the window myself ^^ but can someone help me with the collision part? And sorry for my bad english :/

The java part :

Comment: You need to post some example code to provide context and make things more concrete ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply solution of comparing two co-ordinates based on a radius could be this,

```
public static float compareDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {

        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lat1);
        locationA.setLongitude(lng1);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(lat2);
        locationB.setLongitude(lng2);

        float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

        return distance;
    }
```

This function returns the distance between two places (lat, lng) which can be used to verify if the source and destination is within a specific range.

To use,

```
double distance = compareDistance(source_lat, source_lng, destination_lat, destination_lng);
```

Comment: Tyvm prokash for your answer :) your solution looks good, i think i need to put that into private void setUpMap ... but after i wrote it there, it says me that it expected an class or an interface :/

Comment: Google has a distanceBetween function in Location API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

String Fauna = "51.844188, 8.301594";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.0x110000FF
 */
private void setUpMap() {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(51.844188, 8.301594)).title("Flora und Fauna"));

    // Erschafft einen Neuen Kreis, bei dem Marker Fauna.

    Circle kreis_Fauna_Flora = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(51.844188, 8.301594))
            .radius(200)
            .strokeColor(0xffff0000)
            .fillColor(0x44ff0000)
            .strokeWidth(2f));


    // Erlaubt google maps meine Location zu nutzen
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Ist dazu da das LocationManager aus getSystemService "importiert" wird wofür LocationManager da ist keine ahnung ...
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider (Braucht man um später seine Location zu bestimmen)
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider (Ein string mit dem namen provider wird erschaffen, per LocationManager.getBestProvider wird der Name des providers wiedergegeben, der am besten zu criteria passt ... braucht man auch um seine  LETZTE Location herauszufinden)
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location (Der finala part mit dem mann seine Location bekommt)
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type (hiermit setzte ich den Kartentyp)
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location (Bekommtden Breitengrad meiner Position aus myLocation)
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longtitude of the current location (Bekomme den Längengrad meiner Position aus myLocation)
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location (Latlng speichert die Längengrade und Breitengrade als Koordinaten)
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map (Zeigt die jetzige Location in einer "animation")
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map (Zoomt zu unserer Position, Erschafft danach einen Marker an unserer Position mit der Nachricht "Du bist hier")
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Du bist hier!").snippet("Du hast dich selbst localisiert!"));


   // macht nichts ausser Ein Meldungsfenster zu öffnen ...
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Made by Lars Matthäus").setNeutralButton("ok",null).show();

}
```